# how to check apache and mysql is running or not in java?

Tags: java, android

I want to check apache and MySQL is start or not from java file.

Please tell me Java Code for that..

I call php file in android application..

Then I want to check status.

Comment: You can't expect someone to just give you that, without seeing that you actually tried something.

Comment: You have to possess magic and wisdom.

Comment: "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"
says [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" import="java.io.*, java.net.*" %>

<% 
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("another.apache.com", 80);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter socketOut = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

            socketOut.print("GET /index.html\n\n");
            socketOut.flush();

            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e){}
%>
```

if there is not any exception, your another apache server is running, otherwise it's offline.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code for Unix (Linux/BSD/etc):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -aux");
```

Then read and parse output for string "apache" and "mysql" or add a regexp filter to command using "grep" after pipe ("|").